# How do i parse the XML in powershell to select the items from the last module

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to select the max count and count to do a calculation in PowerShell.

Here is the xml example:

```
<Para TimeStamp="1497627698"
       Signature="6D09881827E0973">
    <License Module="page"
           ServerId="1452"
           EnterBy="20110630"
           RenewDate="20170701"
           RenewPeriod="Year"
           MaxNumWorkflowServers="1"
           MaxVersion="3.0"
           MaxNumExportFields="10"
           TableRecognition="FALSE"
           DisabledOn="20170613">
        <Counter Name="Pages"
             MaxCount="7500"
             Count="7500"/>
    </License>
    <License Module="page"
           ServerId="1452"
           EnterBy="20170613"
           RenewDate="20170701"
           RenewPeriod="Year"
           MaxNumWorkflowServers="1"
           MaxVersion="3.0"
           MaxNumExportFields="10"
           TableRecognition="FALSE"
           ValidUntil="20170620">
        <Counter Name="Pages"
             MaxCount="8000"
             Count="7613"/>
    </License>
</Para>
```

Comment: If you need to do this in Powershell of all things, why did you tag C#/.NET? AFAIK they are not related.

Comment: Your xml document isn´t well formed.

Comment: @k7s5a - It is well formed, but wasn't displayed completely because the formatting was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    [xml]$xml = '
<Para TimeStamp="1497627698"
       Signature="6D09881827E0973">
    <License Module="page"
           ServerId="1452"
           EnterBy="20110630"
           RenewDate="20170701"
           RenewPeriod="Year"
           MaxNumWorkflowServers="1"
           MaxVersion="3.0"
           MaxNumExportFields="10"
           TableRecognition="FALSE"
           DisabledOn="20170613">
        <Counter Name="Pages"
             MaxCount="7500"
             Count="7500"/>
    </License>
    <License Module="page"
           ServerId="1452"
           EnterBy="20170613"
           RenewDate="20170701"
           RenewPeriod="Year"
           MaxNumWorkflowServers="1"
           MaxVersion="3.0"
           MaxNumExportFields="10"
           TableRecognition="FALSE"
           ValidUntil="20170620">
        <Counter Name="Pages"
             MaxCount="8000"
             Count="7613"/>
    </License>
</Para>
'
```

Then execute: `$xml.Para.License.Counter.MaxCount` in your Powershell prompt. That will give you the values for all the max count elements in your xml. You can specify variables for whatever elements you want to operate against after that.

Optionally, if your XML is a file, you can import the file into the `$xml` variable using `[xml]$xml = Get-Content [path_to_your_file]`

Comment: :hi I am actually trying like this '$xml.Para.License.Counter | Select MaxCount'

Comment: :buts its selecting this way:MaxCount:
750000 800000
Count:
2

Comment: Hey @surendrachandaluri, it would help me help you if you told me why that's not what you're wanting to see. In your original question, you said you need to select the count and max count elements and run a calculation on them. You now have a method to select those elements; are you having difficulty performing the calculation?

Comment: I am really sorry , I am not clear I need to select only one value for maxcount and count , its displaying two as of now (more clear I need to select the max one out of two )

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! In that case, there's two things you can do:

`$maxCount | measure -Maximum` will give you a bunch of info, which you might not want.

`($maxCount | measure -Maximum).Maximum` will give you just the largest value in the array.

Comment: Thanks that really helped me , sorry to confuse you , I had came up with a new problem similar to max count I had one more attribute count, but the powershell is taking as count of array and displaying as 2 instead of value

Comment: Glad I could help!